# Set of possible solutions for a convergent series satisfying limit conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, power-series

If I am given a series of the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
$$
with a given set of conditions, such as,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 1 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^2 f(x) = 1
$$
How to determine the set of values $a_n$ that can satisfy this? Clearly, there are two conditions and infinite number of coefficients, but if the coefficients are linked by a recursion relationship (let's say upto two indices in $n$, which implies the relationship is between three terms $a_n$, $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}$), then we have limited number of independent values of $a_n$. In such a scenario, we can directly calculate the set $\{a_n\}$ satisfying the limit conditions.

But the question is like inverse problem of a power-series method to solve differential equations. I am really unable to put a finger on where to begin with this.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = x^{-2}$ does not make sense with a bound variable on the left becoming a free variable on the right and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^{-2}=0$, but $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^2 f(x) = 1$ would make sense

Comment: Sorry, edited it now!

Comment: There is an issue with the convergence of the sum over all $x$.  An example of an $f(x)$ with those limits is $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.  Its Taylor/Laurent series around $x=0$ is $1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\ldots$ while approaching infinity is $x^{-2}-x^{-4}+x^{-6}-\cdots$, neither of which converge when $x=1$